# How do I change the default version of a unix executable?

Tags: macos, unix, which

I currently have two versions of the same executable installed on my OSX machine: one sits in usr/bin, and the other is a Macports installation. When I run `which`, the terminal returns the location to the usr/bin version. Is there a uniform way to change the default installation, or does every application have their own command option for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to modify the `PATH` environment variable.  This is the standard used to search for executables under Unix.

When something on Unix looks for an application that is given with a relative path (eg: `clang` rather than `/usr/bin/clang`), `PATH` is split on the `:` character, and then searched in order.

eg: if your `PATH` is `/opt/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` then `clang` will look for `/opt/local/bin/clang`, and if that is missing, `/bin/clang`, etc.

Technically, every process has their own way to do this - nothing forces them to follow the convention of using `$PATH`, but it has been that way for long enough that pretty much everything does.

The other consideration is that every process has an environment of it's own - a copy of `PATH` included in that.  That includes launchd, which is what is responsible for the UI and any application launched from that.

So, you can modify this in your shell init scripts (`.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc), but that won't work if, eg, you launch vim or emacs as a GUI application.

You can also modify `/etc/paths`, or add a file to `/etc/paths.d`, and that will form part of the standard environment for everything - including every application launched on the Mac.  (You need to log out and back in to have that permeate every part of the system, though.)

Comment: To add to Daniel's answer: MacPort's should have appended an export statement in your .profile or .bash_profile-- It will look like this `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH` If that line is not in there, add it and restart terminal. You can also type `echo $PATH` to see what is currently set in your shell.

Comment: I get the concept of $PATH, but this doesn't really answer my question, which makes me wonder if it's misguided to start with:

My current .profile looks like this:`export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin`. However, for example, the default clang installation is in usr/bin. It's not clear to me to how to force the Macports installation to be the default.

Comment: Oh.  I updated the answer to reflect how PATH is searched in practice, but: put the directory containing the executables you prefer earlier in PATH.  Beyond that, though, there isn't a concept of "default" application at the Unix level like there is at the OSX UI level.  It is just "whatever comes first in the path".

Answer (score 2):

If modifying `$PATH` is not feasible for whatever reason, you can create an **alias** that invokes the executable in the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 0):

The `PATH` variable defines where your commands are.

You may modify this variable in your `/etc/paths` file.
You should verify that `/usr/bin` is before others.